# Solitaire Klondike on Java

Tags: java, swing

For my end of semester project I have to do a solitaire klondike game on java.

So far, I've made a class called Card, with all the attributes. I've also made a jFrame. It has an `ArrayList` with all the cards, which I've already put in random order, and divided them into the other 7 decks.

The problem is at the moment of painting the cards, only one deck has one card visible under the other. For the resting decks I can't seem to achieve it. Also, I' can't put the card facing down.

Here's my code and an Image of the graphic interface.

**GUI Code**

```
package solitario;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Andres
 */
public class Applet extends javax.swing.JApplet {
//Creo el ArrayList del mazo principal

    private ArrayList<Carta> mazoPrincipal;
    private ArrayList<Carta> mazoUno;
    private ArrayList<Carta> mazoDos;
    private ArrayList<Carta> mazoTres;
    private ArrayList<Carta> mazoCuatro;
    private ArrayList<Carta> mazoCinco;
    private ArrayList<Carta> mazoSeis;
    private ArrayList<Carta> mazoSiete;

    /**
     * Initializes the applet Applet
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Applet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Applet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Applet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Applet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the applet */
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                    mazoPrincipal = new ArrayList<Carta>();
                    //Agrego Tréboles
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 1, "/imagenes/treboles/1.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 2, "/imagenes/treboles/49.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 3, "/imagenes/treboles/45.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 4, "/imagenes/treboles/41.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 5, "/imagenes/treboles/37.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 6, "/imagenes/treboles/33.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 7, "/imagenes/treboles/29.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 8, "/imagenes/treboles/25.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 9, "/imagenes/treboles/21.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 10, "/imagenes/treboles/17.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 11, "/imagenes/treboles/13.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 12, "/imagenes/treboles/9.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Trebol", 13, "/imagenes/treboles/5.png"));

                    //Agrego Picas
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 1, "/imagenes/picas/2.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 2, "/imagenes/picas/50.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 3, "/imagenes/picas/46.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 4, "/imagenes/picas/42.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 5, "/imagenes/picas/38.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 6, "/imagenes/picas/34.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 7, "/imagenes/picas/30.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 8, "/imagenes/picas/26.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 9, "/imagenes/picas/22.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 10, "/imagenes/picas/18.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 11, "/imagenes/picas/14.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 12, "/imagenes/picas/10.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Negro", false, "Picas", 13, "/imagenes/picas/6.png"));

                    //Agrego Corazones
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 1, "/imagenes/corazones/3.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 2, "/imagenes/corazones/51.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 3, "/imagenes/corazones/47.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 4, "/imagenes/corazones/43.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 5, "/imagenes/corazones/39.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 6, "/imagenes/corazones/35.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 7, "/imagenes/corazones/31.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 8, "/imagenes/corazones/27.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 9, "/imagenes/corazones/23.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 10, "/imagenes/corazones/19.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 11, "/imagenes/corazones/15.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 12, "/imagenes/corazones/11.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Corazones", 13, "/imagenes/corazones/7.png"));

                    //Agrego Diamantes
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 1, "/imagenes/diamantes/4.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 2, "/imagenes/diamantes/52.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 3, "/imagenes/diamantes/48.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 4, "/imagenes/diamantes/44.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 5, "/imagenes/diamantes/40.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 6, "/imagenes/diamantes/36.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 7, "/imagenes/diamantes/32.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 8, "/imagenes/diamantes/28.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 9, "/imagenes/diamantes/24.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 10, "/imagenes/diamantes/20.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 11, "/imagenes/diamantes/16.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 12, "/imagenes/diamantes/12.png"));
                    mazoPrincipal.add(new Carta("Rojo", false, "Diamantes", 13, "/imagenes/diamantes/8.png"));

                    //Inicializa mazos
                    mazoUno = new ArrayList<Carta>();
                    mazoDos = new ArrayList<Carta>();
                    mazoTres = new ArrayList<Carta>();
                    mazoCuatro = new ArrayList<Carta>();
                    mazoCinco = new ArrayList<Carta>();
                    mazoSeis = new ArrayList<Carta>();
                    mazoSiete = new ArrayList<Carta>();
                    //Desordena mazo
                    Collections.shuffle(mazoPrincipal);
                    repartir();

//                    pinta();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
     * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        labelMazo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        panelMazoDos = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panelMazoUno = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panelMazoTres = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panelMazoCuatro = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panelMazoCinco = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panelMazoSeis = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panelMazoSiete = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0));
        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        labelMazo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/b1fv.png"))); // NOI18N
        labelMazo.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                labelMazoMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(labelMazo, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 20, 71, 96));

        panelMazoDos.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0));
        panelMazoDos.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        panelMazoDos.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        jPanel1.add(panelMazoDos, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(110, 180, 70, 160));

        panelMazoUno.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0));
        panelMazoUno.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        panelMazoUno.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        jPanel1.add(panelMazoUno, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 180, 70, 160));

        panelMazoTres.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0));
        panelMazoTres.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        panelMazoTres.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        jPanel1.add(panelMazoTres, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(200, 180, 70, 160));

        panelMazoCuatro.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0));
        panelMazoCuatro.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        panelMazoCuatro.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        jPanel1.add(panelMazoCuatro, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(290, 180, 70, 160));

        panelMazoCinco.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0));
        panelMazoCinco.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        panelMazoCinco.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        jPanel1.add(panelMazoCinco, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(390, 180, 70, 160));

        panelMazoSeis.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0));
        panelMazoSeis.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        panelMazoSeis.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        jPanel1.add(panelMazoSeis, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(490, 180, 70, 160));

        panelMazoSiete.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0));
        panelMazoSiete.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        panelMazoSiete.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        jPanel1.add(panelMazoSiete, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(580, 180, 70, 160));

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 680, 470));
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void labelMazoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:


    }                                      

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel labelMazo;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelMazoCinco;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelMazoCuatro;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelMazoDos;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelMazoSeis;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelMazoSiete;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelMazoTres;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelMazoUno;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    public void repartir() {
        //Agrega cartas a los demás mazos
        for (int i = 0; i < mazoPrincipal.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {

                mazoUno.add(mazoPrincipal.get(i));

            }
            if (i >= 1 && i < 3) {

                mazoDos.add(mazoPrincipal.get(i));

            }

            if (i >= 3 && i < 6) {
                mazoTres.add(mazoPrincipal.get(i));
            }

            if (i >= 6 && i < 10) {
                mazoCuatro.add(mazoPrincipal.get(i));
            }

            if (i >= 10 && i < 15) {
                mazoCinco.add(mazoPrincipal.get(i));
            }

            if (i >= 15 && i < 21) {
                mazoSeis.add(mazoPrincipal.get(i));
            }

            if (i >= 21 && i < 28) {
                mazoSiete.add(mazoPrincipal.get(i));
            }
        }//Fin For
        //Pinta la carta en el mazo correspondiente. 

        int i = -1;
        for (Carta c : mazoUno) {
            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoUno.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1));
        }

        for (Carta c : mazoDos) {
            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoDos.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, i, -1, -1));
            i += 15;
        }

        for (Carta c : mazoTres) {

            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoTres.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, 0, -1, -1));
            i += 15;
        }
        for (Carta c : mazoCuatro) {
            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoCuatro.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1));
            i += 15;
        }

        for (Carta c : mazoCinco) {
            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoCinco.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1));
            i += 15;
        }

        for (Carta c : mazoSeis) {
            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoSeis.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, i, -1));
            i += 15;
            i++;
        }
        for (Carta c : mazoSiete) {
            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoSiete.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1));
            i += 15;

        }

    }

}//Fin método repartir
```

**Card Class**

```
package solitario;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
/**
 *
 * @author $Andrés Avila Wille
 */
public class Carta extends JLabel{
    private String color;
    private boolean con;
    private String escudo;
    private int num;

    public Carta(){
    }

    public Carta(String color, boolean con, String escudo, int num, String URL) {
        this.color = color;
        this.con = con;
        this.escudo = escudo;
        this.num = num;
        this.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(URL)));
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isCon() {
        return con;
    }

    public void setCon(boolean con) {
        this.con = con;
    }

    public String getEscudo() {
        return escudo;
    }

    public void setEscudo(String escudo) {
        this.escudo = escudo;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void vuelta(boolean con){
        if(con == true){
            this.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/b1fv.png")));
        }
    }



}
```

**GUI Image**

[image: GUI Image]

Comment: This is likely a z-ordering issue, consider having a look at `JLayeredPane`...

Comment: I have, but I can't seem to apply on this.

Answer (score 1):

Prefered solution would be to use [`JLayeredPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) as it provides better control over the z-ordering of the components, failing that, you fake it to a certain extent by using [`Container#add(Component, Object, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29)

So, basically, whenever you add a card to the UI, you need to do something like...

```
panelMazoUno.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1), 0);
```

With out z-order correction...

[image: without]

With z-order correction...

[image: With]

Which is accomplished by simply using...

```
for (Carta c : mazoUno) {
    c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
    panelMazoUno.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1), 0);
}

for (Carta c : mazoDos) {
    c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
    panelMazoDos.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, i, -1, -1), 0);
    i += 15;
}

for (Carta c : mazoTres) {

    c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
    panelMazoTres.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, 0, -1, -1), 0);
    i += 15;
}
for (Carta c : mazoCuatro) {
    c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
    panelMazoCuatro.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1), 0);
    i += 15;
}

for (Carta c : mazoCinco) {
    c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
    panelMazoCinco.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1), 0);
    i += 15;
}

for (Carta c : mazoSeis) {
    c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
    panelMazoSeis.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, i, -1), 0);
    i += 15;
    i++;
}
for (Carta c : mazoSiete) {
    c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
    panelMazoSiete.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1), 0);
    i += 15;

}
```

Comment: I'll try to do a little more research on the `JLayeredPane`. I'll also try adding the 0 to the add.

Comment: Nope, the 0 at the end of panelUno.add is not working.

Comment: @AndrésAvilaWille Then you must be doing something else, cause it works for, see update...

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks a lot for that. However, the other 5 decks still appear wrong.

Comment: This is why JLayedPane would work better, you could define the z-ordering to a much finer level

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of testing, I've come to a solution to this problem. What went wrong was that every For Each iterating had the same `i` index. So, I created a for that initialized a different `i` index for every deck. Also, I used the i index to set its value to the Y position in `c.setBounds()` and `AbsoluteConstraints()` This is my code:

```
for (Carta c : mazoUno) {
        int i = 0;
        c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
        panelMazoUno.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, -1, -1, -1), 0);


    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mazoDos.size();) {
        for (Carta c : mazoDos) {
            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoDos.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, i, -1, -1), 0);
            i += 15;

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mazoTres.size();) {
        for (Carta c : mazoTres) {

            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoTres.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, i, -1, -1), 0);
            i += 15;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mazoCuatro.size();) {
        for (Carta c : mazoCuatro) {
            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoCuatro.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, i, -1, -1), 0);
            i += 15;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mazoCinco.size();) {
        for (Carta c : mazoCinco) {

            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoCinco.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, i, -1, -1), 0);
            i += 15;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mazoSeis.size();) {
        for (Carta c : mazoSeis) {
            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoSeis.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, i, -1, -1), 0);
            i += 15;

        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < mazoSiete.size();) {
        for (Carta c : mazoSiete) {

            c.setBounds(0, i, 50, 100);
            panelMazoSiete.add(c, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-1, i, -1, -1), 0);
            i += 15;

        }
    }
```

And it looks like this: 
[image]